# Help parsing 無事勝利

Tags: meaning, parsing

I'm not sure about the meaning of this sentences:

> ロリンズはヘル・イン・ア・セルPPVで俺がオーエンズに**無事勝利**したらこのリストを返してやる。

Is it saying that at ヘル・イン・ア・セルPPV, ロリンズ is going to return the リスト if he gets a clean victory over オーエンズ, because in the original broadcast(this is a Japanese translation of a wrestling broadcast) it says a different thing(it never anything about ロリンズ giving back the リスト after ヘル・イン・ア・セルPPV). I don't think 無事 is an adjective because adj + noun + する is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

無事勝利 is two words. Here 無事 is used as an adverb which means "without trouble" or "safely". 勝利 is a simple suru-verb that means "to win".

無事 here is interchangeable with 無事に. I think you already know how to turn a no- or na-adjective into an adverb by adding に. Some words work as standalone adverbs without に as well as standard adjectives.

- 絶対に = 絶対 = absolutely: 絶対に勝利する = 絶対勝利する
- 突然に = 突然 = suddenly: 突然に思い出す = 突然思い出す
- 大変に = 大変 = very/strongly: 大変にありがたい = 大変ありがたい

However 確実 (certain) and 唐突 (sudden) do *not* work as standalone adverbs. It depends.

Comment: So, is it saying that ロリンズ is going to return the list after his victory over オーエンズ？

Comment: @Jon Actually this sentence is malformed. Looks like [the author of this article has a bad habit of omitting brackets altogether when clearly necessary](http://aozora-pwresult.com/archives/4924). Anyway 「ヘル・イン・ア・セルPPVで俺がオーエンズに無事勝利したらこのリストを返してやる」 means "I will return this list if I have beaten Owens," yes.

Comment: Well that shocks me a bit, I noticed that too but I that adding という at the end of the sentence was enough. I also read translations from jabroni.typepad.jp/wwe and they do use brackets but no という at the end. I thought it was just different styles.