# エリスが去った理由を自分に愛想をつかしたと勘違いしたルーデウスは、失意のまま行方不明の家族を探す旅にでる。

Tags: grammar

> エリスが去った理由を自分に愛想をつかしたと勘違いしたルーデウスは、失意のまま行方不明の家族を探す旅にでる。

How to combine the following components?

1. エリスが去った理由 -> the reason that Erisu left
2. 自分に愛想をつかしたと勘違いしたルーデウスは -> Rudeusu, who misunderstood and (??) used up friendliness himself (???)
3. 失意のまま -> heart-broken state (Is this treated as an adverb? If so, for 探す or でる?)
4. 行方不明の家族を探す旅にでる -> goes out (starts) a trip to find the missing families.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sentence has a [`Aを + Bと + verb` construction](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/55169/5010), where A is エリスが去った理由 and B is 自分に愛想をつかした(こと). And [(～に)愛想を尽かす is a set phrase](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%84%9B%E6%83%B3%E3%82%92%E5%B0%BD%E3%81%8B%E3%81%99) meaning "to run out of patience with ～", "to give up on ～".

> エリスが去った理由を自分に愛想をつかしたと勘違いしたルーデウスは、...
> Rudeus, who mistakenly thought that the reason Eris left was because she ran out of patience with him, ...
> Having mistaken Eris's departure as a sign that she gave up on him, Rudeus...
>
> ...失意のまま...
> ...while still being disappointed, ...
> <sub>(Adverbially modifies (旅に)出る. まま is one of the no-adjectives that can [also work as an adverb without に](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/41536/5010). This part could have been 失意のまま**に**, too.)</sub>
>
> ...行方不明の家族を探す旅にでる。
> ...starts a trip to find his missing family members.